# VBA coding for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling in making a code with a for loop over all worksheets of the workbook to work. I've tried to implement the task just for one tab and it works though. Here's the code so that you can have a look.

```
Sub testing()
 
    Dim LandedCost As Range
    Dim UnitSell As Range
    Dim TotalUnitPrice As Range
    Dim Profit As Range
    Dim tier2 As Range
    Dim Mtrs As Range
    Dim NetProfit As Range
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim first_col As Range
    Dim last_col As Range
    Dim last_col_cur As Range
    y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    
    For i = 2 To y
        Sheets(2).Range("N3").Select
        Selection.Copy
    
        Set LandedCost = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Landed Cost")
        Set UnitSell = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Unit Sell")
        Set TotalUnitPrice = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Total Unit Price")
        Set Profit = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Profit")
        Set tier2 = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("TIER-2")
        Set NetProfit = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Net Profit")
        Set Mtrs = Sheets(i).Range("A1:K1").Find("Unit Price-Ref Mtrs")
    
        'first_col = LandedCost.Column
        'last_col = TotalUnitPrice.Column
        'last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'last_col_cur = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 'for currency'
    
        If Not IsNull(TotalUnitPrice) Then     Sheets(i).Range(Cells(LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row,LandedCost.Column),Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, TotalUnitPrice.Column)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.Union(Columns(LandedCost.Column), Columns(UnitSell.Column), Columns(TotalUnitPrice.Column)).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In Sheets(i).Range(Cells(1, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, TotalUnitPrice.Column))
                If cell = 0 Then cell.ClearContents
            Next cell
                
        ElseIf Not IsNull(UnitSell) Then
            Sheets(i).Range(Cells(LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 20, UnitSell.Column)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.Union(Columns(LandedCost.Column), Columns(UnitSell.Column)).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            For Each cell In Sheets(i).Range(Cells(1, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, UnitSell.Column))
                If cell = 0 Then cell.ClearContents
            Next cell
            
        ElseIf Not IsNull(tier2) Then
            Sheets(i).Range(Cells(LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 20, tier2.Column)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.Union(Columns(LandedCost.Column), Columns(UnitSell.Column), Columns(tier2.Column)).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            For Each cell In Sheets(i).Range(Cells(1, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, tier2.Column))
                If cell = 0 Then cell.ClearContents
            Next cell
            
        ElseIf Not IsNull(Mtrs) Then
            Sheets(i).Range(Cells(LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 20, Mtrs.Column)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.Union(Columns(LandedCost.Column), Columns(UnitSell.Column), Columns(Mtrs.Column)).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            For Each cell In Sheets(i).Range(Cells(1, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Mtrs.Column))
                If cell = 0 Then cell.ClearContents
            Next cell
        End If
        
        If Not IsNull(Profit) Then
            Columns(Profit.Column).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        ElseIf Not IsNull(NetProfit) Then
            Columns(NetProfit.Column).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am getting errors like, that I do not set the necessary variables, that I need to activate the workbook for Range.Select to work or even that I do not declare variables. Although, for all these I already do so and it works for a single tab. Here's the code so that you can have a look..

I initially define the commented variables as you can see and I use those inside the if statements. But I still get errors even for those.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `.Select` in your VBA as it usually causes more issues than what solves. Generally when people use `Select` they want to obtain a `Range` object. Though many of VBA's method actually return a `Range` object.

In the below I have rewritten your first `If` statement to work with only `Range` objects and not use `Select`

Another remark, put all the paste and clearing stuff into a separate `Sub()` so that you simply call that sub rather than to duplicate all the same -confusing- code in all your `If...else` statements.

In addition -and I believe you already made a start with that- reduce the number of `Cells(<some long code>, <some other long code>)` statements and reduce to setting these `Integer/Long` values to variables before processing, that will keep your code much cleaner and would make it easier to separate the paste and format actions to a separate `Sub()`

See if the below works;

```
Sub testing()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range, cpy As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 
    Dim LandedCost As Range
    Dim UnitSell As Range
    Dim TotalUnitPrice As Range
    Dim Profit As Range
    Dim tier2 As Range
    Dim Mtrs As Range
    Dim NetProfit As Range
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim first_col As Range
    Dim last_col As Range
    Dim last_col_cur As Range
    'y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    
    'For i = 2 To y
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    
        Set searchRng = ws.Range("A1:K1")
    
        Set cpy = Sheets(2).Range("N3")
    
        Set LandedCost = searchRng.Find("Landed Cost")
        Set UnitSell = searchRng.Find("Unit Sell")
        Set TotalUnitPrice = searchRng.Find("Total Unit Price")
        Set Profit = searchRng.Find("Profit")
        Set tier2 = searchRng.Find("TIER-2")
        Set NetProfit = searchRng.Find("Net Profit")
        Set Mtrs = searchRng.Find("Unit Price-Ref Mtrs")
    
        'first_col = LandedCost.Column
        'last_col = TotalUnitPrice.Column
        'last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'last_col_cur = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 'for currency'
    
        If Not IsNull(TotalUnitPrice) Then
            Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, TotalUnitPrice.Column))
            
            rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            
            Set rng = Application.Union(Columns(LandedCost.Column), Columns(UnitSell.Column), Columns(TotalUnitPrice.Column))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            rng.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            ws.Range(Cells(1, LandedCost.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, TotalUnitPrice.Column)).ClearContents
                
        '...rest of your if else statements
        
        End If
        
        If Not IsNull(Profit) Then
            Columns(Profit.Column).Select
            cpy.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        ElseIf Not IsNull(NetProfit) Then
            Columns(NetProfit.Column).Select
            cpy.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

Your code, but refactored (though arguably **NOT** tested as I do not have your data)

```
Private Function FindRange(ws As Worksheet, arg As String) As Range

    Set FindRange = ws.Range("A1:K1").Find(arg)
    
End Function

Private Sub ClearRange(ws As Worksheet, col1 As Long, col2 As Long)

    Set C1 = ws.Cells(1, col1)
    Set C2 = ws.Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, col2)
    ws.Range(C1, C2).ClearContents
    
End Sub    
    
Sub Testing()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 
    Dim LandedCost As Range
    Dim UnitSell As Range
    Dim TotalUnitPrice As Range
    Dim Profit As Range
    Dim tier2 As Range
    Dim Mtrs As Range
    Dim NetProfit As Range
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim first_col As Long
    Dim last_col As Long
    Dim last_col_cur As Long
    'y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    
    'For i = 2 To y
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Index = 1) Then GoTo 100
        
        Set cpy = Sheets(2).Range("N3")
        cpy.Copy
    
        Set LandedCost = FindRange(ws, "Landed Cost")
        Set UnitSell = FindRange(ws, "Unit Sell")
        Set TotalUnitPrice = FindRange(ws, "Total Unit Price")
        Set Profit = FindRange(ws, "Profit")
        Set tier2 = FindRange(ws, "TIER-2")
        Set NetProfit = FindRange(ws, "Net Profit")
        Set Mtrs = FindRange(ws, "Unit Price-Ref Mtrs")
        
        landedCostLastRow = LandedCost.End(xlDown).Row
        first_col = LandedCost.Column
        last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        last_col_cur = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 'for currency'
        
        Set C1 = Cells(landedCostLastRow, first_col)
        Set rngUnion = Application.Union(Columns(first_col), Columns(UnitSell.Column))
    
        If Not IsNull(TotalUnitPrice) Then
            
            Set C2 = Cells(last_row, TotalUnitPrice.Column)
            Set rng = ws.Range(C1, C2)
            rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                
            Set rngUnion = Application.Union(rngUnion, Columns(TotalUnitPrice.Column))
            rngUnion.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            ClearRange ws, first_col, TotalUnitPrice.Column
                
        ElseIf Not IsNull(UnitSell) Then
        
            Set C2 = Cells(last_row + 20, UnitSell.Column)
            ws.Range(C1, C2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
            rngUnion.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            ClearRange ws, first_col, UnitSell.Column
            
        ElseIf Not IsNull(tier2) Then
        
            Set C2 = Cells(last_row + 20, tier2.Column)
            ws.Range(C1, C2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                
            Set rngUnion = Application.Union(rngUnion, Columns(tier2.Column))
            rng.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            ClearRange ws, first_col, tier2.Column
            
        ElseIf Not IsNull(Mtrs) Then
        
            Set C2 = Cells(last_row + 20, Mtrs.Column)
            ws.Range(C1, C2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                
            Set rngUnion = Application.Union(rngUnion, Columns(Mtrs.Column))
            rngUnion.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
            
            ClearRange ws, first_col, Mtrs.Column
            
        End If
        
        If Not IsNull(Profit) Then
            Columns(Profit.Column).Select
            cpy.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        ElseIf Not IsNull(NetProfit) Then
            Columns(NetProfit.Column).Select
            cpy.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        End If
        
100:
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks very tidy after your edits. Thank you for that. Although, it still does not work, I get a type mismatch error while we set the variables when calling the FindRange function. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @KonstantinosAzas I have corrected the code, though I cannot say or guarantee this will do exactly as you wish as I do not have your data to test against. The goal here is to assist you on your path to coding this solution yourself? So, if an error does indeed occur see if you can try to understand what goes wrong, step through your code using F8 & F5. That way you will learn what the code does and you can correct it yourself? If you get stuck, then you can ask a question on SO

Comment: I have tried to re-write it.Your code is correct and it's making sense to what I am trying to achieve.I still, and I don't know why, get run-time errors 91 which are basically that I am not setting my variables.It starts to pop when we define landedCostLastRow etc. When I do set all variables, I again get errors that I did not declare variables correctly (which I do, I declare them as Long).The only thing that I thought it would be the case is is I should declare variables within the for loop our at the beginning as I do.The same with setting them.But I doubt it will change something.

Comment: Can you submit an example file via Doprbox or WeTransfer or so?

Comment: Yes, drop me an email address.

Comment: Try this one, you can drop the file there: https://www.dropbox.com/request/OrM8tIeSWmpmAhua308q

Comment: Okay, I have just uploaded the files. It is an excel sheet with the data, a text file with the code and another text file with instructions. Let me know for further updates.

Comment: @KonstantinosAzas, can you include your email in any of the files so we can communicate on the content of your XL sheet?

Comment: yes, I have just uploaded on your Dropbox a text file with my email address.